# Coredata performBlockAndWait executeFetchRequest getting null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

Below is my code i am trying to fetch contain from coredata entity on privatequeue but in return i got null value.

```
-(NSArray *)fetch_agenda_for_financialdoc:(BOOL)isFinace
{
    __block NSArray *fetchRecords;
    NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [private setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [private performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AgendaDetails" inManagedObjectContext:private];
        [request setEntity:entity];      
        NSError *error;
        fetchRecords = [private executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
     }];
    for (AgendaDetails *obj in fetchRecords) {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj.agendaName);
    }
    return fetchRecords;
}
```

If more detail required i can give you thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing the objects out of the block anyway, it's a thread violation

Comment: than how to pass objects out of the block?

Comment: you pass the object ids and then get them in the other context - you wouldn't usually just fetch in a different context...

Comment: thanks @Wain for your suggestion but can you please show a small demo stuff.